# How to return new array of type different from the original array in java

Tags: java, arrays, types

Hello Everyone I'm having toughest time in my career figuring this out.
Here I have commented on the code so the problem could be easily spotted.
I wish someone can rescue me, thanks to that rescuer in advance.
**Code below**

```
public class Marathon {
    /** The whole point here is: how can I return a new arr which is of type Marathon */
    static int [][] raceValues;

    public Marathon(int aValue){
        this.raceValues = [aValue][aValue]; // (Problem no.1) Erroneously accessing a static variable nonstatically
        for (int i = 1; i <= aValue; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= aValue; j++) {
                this.raceValues[i-1][j-1] = (aValue * (i - (aValue - (aValue - 1)))) + j;
            }
        }
    }

    Marathon alterAnyValue(int a){
    /*
    *  If I could write something like next line, then my problem would be solved. But eclipse will grizzle
    *  "Cannot convert from int to Marathon"
    *  Marathon arr[][] = raceValues;
    */
    int arr[][] = raceValues; 
    for (int i = 0; i < aValue; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < aValue; j++) {
            int c = arr[i][j] % 3; // Divisible by three
            int d = arr[i][j] % 5;  // Divisible by five
            if(c == 0){
                arr[i][j] = 3;
            }

            if(d == 0){
                arr[i][j] == 5;
            }
        }
    }
    /*
    * Here I don't know how to return new arr
    * I must return a new arr and it must be of type Maraton
    * At this point the whole world just ended. I don't know what to do
    */
    //return new Marathon()
    //return arr
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should the return type be `Marathon` at all?

Comment: Turn around and *see* if the world just ended! Please, tell me what you saw.

Comment: Yes the return type must be Marathon.

Answer (score -1):

For your first Problem: The static accessing: You can do `Marathon.raceValues = new int[aValue][aValue];` This would solve your Static Access "error"

For your second problem I don't see a possibility in Java as you can't make new "Integer" classes as they are final. You COULD make your own Integer but I couldn't imagin WHY. So the other possibility could be that you return an Integer Array.

This would be what I would try to do. If you want something different please specify the question a bit better :)